# What does "that guy's goin' somewhere" mean here?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Here is the full text:

> Wait a second, you're telling me, this masterpiece I wouldn't mind seeing in a commercial game was only the creator's second map ever released?
> ***Well, if that doesn't scream "that guy's goin' somewhere", I don't know what will.*** And getting highlighted by someone like you is gonna probably give them more positive attention. Nice, everyone wins.

This guy was really amazed at not only how talented a game mapper (for Doom) was, who had made a map that he thought was a masterpiece, but that it was only the second map that he had made ever for that game to boot.

So, to express his great surprise and admiration, he wrote this as a comment below a video of gameplay footage of that map.

Could you please tell me what the phrase marked bold means, and whether it's an idiom?

Comment: It's great that you provided details but citations should always be attributed. Could you tell us where your source is from, please?  The title of the book, movie or does it come from an online game?  Thanks.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Okay,I'll add that next time, than you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"he is going somewhere" is an informal expression that means the same as the more formal expression "he will [go far](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-far)". Both suggest that you expect them to achieve a lot.